# Google script - Add 1 to a cell on every export

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a way to create an automatic number on Google Sheets. Might be simple but I don't know much about script...

The process would be that every time a user downloads the sheet, the number in A1 goes up one.

Answer (score 0):

Use otOInkInit to setup the intial value in the PropertiesService. Then you can put loadSerial into you download script.

```
function onOpen(e)
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('otOInk','otOInk')
    .addItem('otOInkInit', 'otOInkInit')
    .addItem('loadSerial', 'loadSerial')
    .addToUi();
}

//provides an otOInk number and increments to the next one 
function otOInk() 
{
  var num=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('otOInk');
  if(num)
  {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('otOInk',Number(num)+1);
    return num;
  }
}
//use to setup the otOInk property in the PropertiesService
function otOInkInit(initialValue)
{
  var initialValue=(typeof(initialValue)!='undefined')?initialValue:0;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('otOInk',initialValue);
}
//loads the otOInk number into a cell of a named sheet
function loadSerial(cellA1Notation,sheetName)
{
  var cellA1Notation=(typeof(cellA1Notation)!='undefined')?cellA1Notation:'A1';
  var sheetName=(typeof(sheetName)!='undefined')?sheetName:'Sheet1';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var cell=sht.getRange(cellA1Notation);
  cell.setValue(otOInk());
}
```